# Assign matrix element using CSML library

Tags: c#

After creating an array using CSML library in c#, how do you store integer elements into the array ? I tried something like this

```
Matrix A = new Matrix (10, 10);
A [2, 2] = 10;
Console.Write (A [2, 2]);
```

I could not get through with this. Is there any way I can make that array accept integer elements?

Comment: "can not implicitly convert type "int" to "CSML.Complex" - this is what it says..

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code of the `Matrix` class (available on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19032/C-Matrix-Library)), the signature of the indexer is the following

```
public virtual Complex this[int i, int j]
```

The `Complex` class is defined in the same library.

So what you need to do is

```
Matrix A = new Matrix (10, 10);
A [2, 2] = new Complex(10);
Console.Write (A [2, 2]);
```

The `Complex` constructor with one argument assumes 0 for the imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that is the only way to do it. Thanks for the information! This works.

Comment: Did anyone try using the Arg command with CSML? I get an error saying "Arg" is not available in this context.

Comment: What is `Arg` supposed to do? I don't see it anywhere. Also if you found this answer helpful you can upvote/accept it.

Comment: "public static double Arg(Complex z) computes the argument of the complex number z," This is a line from the documentation of CSML. It calculates the angle of the complex number.
I thank you. Your answer was helpful however I can not upvote anything right now because I do not have enough posts/reputation yet.

Comment: Oh right you have to use it like this `var c = new Complex(10); Complex.Arg(c);`.